# No clicks received over chromeless YT player

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, youtube

I'm using [jquery youtube player plugin](https://github.com/badsyntax/jquery-youtube-player) to embed a chromeless YT player (`width: 100%, height: 100%`) on my single-page site. 
My goal is to give user a "no brainer" and "no mouse hassle" feature to simply click anywhere within movie to play/pause it. No other controls.

While the plugin perfectly handles wmode issue, on IE, it seems to fall into another problem where the big "click to play" button does not receive any clicks. In fact nothing does. I have tried various jquery selectors, like `$(document)`, `$('object', someContext)`, etc. but no trace of clicks in my `console.log()`.

I tried to use this plugin's config parameter's toolbar, with a play button spread all over the movie - to no avail.

Has anybody been through this? Is it possible to achieve, is it that cross-domain thingy involved?